# Maintaining Global Declarations while Cleaning up Type Exports in Vite with React and vite-plugin-dts

Tags: reactjs, types, build, vite

I'm using Vite with React and I'm building an application which exports to a web component.

In my vite.config.ts I'm using vite-plugin-dts to create a index.d.ts:

```js
export default defineConfig({
  plugins:[
    // ... other plugins
    dts({
      rollupTypes: true,
    }),
  ],

  // other config
});
```

```js
import type { HTMLAttributes } from 'react';

// some other exports

export type Props = HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>;

declare global {
  namespace JSX {
    interface IntrinsicElements {
      'web-component': Props;
    }
  }
}
```

But using `rollupTypes` removes the global declaration which I need for my consumers to use without getting an error. I've tried removing `rollupTypes` so it won't remove the global declaration but also keeps a ton of other types which I don't want to expose.

How can I keep the global declaration and have a clean export of types, i.e. using rollupTypes but keep the global declaration?